# Flipping the coin until either head or tail has occurred 10 times

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem

> The probability that a head faces up is 0.4. Peter keep flipping the coin independently until either head or tail has occurred 10 times in total.
>
> (a) Find the probability that the coin is flipped 10 times.
>
> (b) Find the probability that the coin is flipped 12 times.

I think I should apply binomial probability law, but I tried many times, still cannot figure out the answer, please help.

Comment: I'm a beginner but here's my 2 cents... in regards to b) I think you should use the negative binomial. Because in your problem you want the last flip to be a success. The last outcome being a success is not mandatory for the binomial RV. Or, you could use the binomial RV but for the first 11 flips only because you know the outcome of the 12th flip. Which is basically the negative binomial.

Comment: Surely you can do (a)? There are only two possibilities, either the coin came up heads 10 times in a row, or it came up tails 10 times in a row. What is the probability for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In regards to a)**

Flipping 10 times means that you either get all heads in a row or all tails in a row. So the answer is $(0.4)^{10} + (0.6)^{10}$

**In regards to b)**

$$\binom{11}{9}(0.6)^{10}(0.4)^{2} + \binom{11}{9}(0.4)^{10}(0.6)^{2}$$

The reasoning is you know the outcome of the last flip. In the case you get $10$ heads the last flip must be heads. So that means you have $11$ spots to arrange $9$ heads. Then you just add the case where you win with tails.

**Word of caution**

I am a beginner so I could be wrong. See if this makes sense to you.

Comment: It makes sense.  It has also spoon fed kdhug886 the entire solution rather than just providing hints to lead the way.